# multi update only works with $ operators in mongodb,Replace document Entirely

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

I want to replace some document entirely with **multi:true** option.

```
db.user.find().pretty();
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5799b106d15203df993935d9"),
        "name" : "zhangyun",
        "age" : 33
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5799b4d9e21ce60703d1e1c7"),
        "name" : "zhangli",
        "age" : 12
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5799b5afe21ce60703d1e1c8"),
        "name" : "zhangyun",
        "height" : 1.75
    }
```

I want to do update operation.like this:

```
db.user.update({name:"zhangyun"},{sex:"male"},{multi:true})
```

I got "**multi update only works with $ operators**" error

the mongodb official document

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter
just tell me it cannot,but no why and how to do in such cases.

can anybody help me with this problem ?

Comment: Notice:i want to replace entirely ,not to add the sex field

Comment: it's not duplicate question with the question you marked.@chridam

Comment: The error says it all `"multi update only works with $ operators"`, the answer in the marked duplicate addresses that, you need the `$set` operator even if you want to replace the entire document, not just the sex field.

Comment: i want to update and get result like this:  
   ‘{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5799b106d15203df993935d9"),
        "sex" : "male"
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5799b4d9e21ce60703d1e1c7"),
        "name" : "zhangli",
        "age" : 12
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5799b5afe21ce60703d1e1c8"),
        "sex" : "male"
    } ’ so how to do?

Comment: Maybe it's not meaningful operation.that is,we won't do this because if we do so,then the collection exists two document same with each other except the _id field.